# How to convert between the different color models in Mathematica?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I never noticed this before, but it seems obvious, isn't there some way to convert from, say, `Hue` to `RGBColor`?  I looked for (the canonical) `HueToRGBColor`, and I tried `Hue[RGBColor[1,0,0]]`, all to no avail.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The function you're looking for is [`ColorConvert`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ColorConvert.html?q=ColorConvert&lang=en). So for your example:

```
ColorConvert[Red,"HSB"]
Out[1]= Hue[0., 1., 1.]
```

and the reverse:

```
ColorConvert[Hue[0, 1, 1], "RGB"]
RGBColor[1., 0., 0.]
```